# Styling CSS pseudoclasses in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, pseudo-class

I need to apply some CSS rules to `::before` and `::after`, but I can't figure out how.

I tried passing **inline styles** to my component like this (using JSX):

```
const color: '#fff';

const style = {
  '::before': { backgroundColor: color },
  '::after': { backgroundColor: color },
};

<div style={ style }>
```

I tried other permutations as well, such as `':before'`, `'&::before'`, `before`... nothing seems to work.

Is this even supported by React? If so, what's the right way of doing it **using inline styles**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react's inline styles don't support css pseudo-classes. Or media queries. You could either write plain css, or use a lib for that https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Answer (score 0):

You can style-loader to your webpack config.

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a style tag, when you import any css in your component.

```
import style from './file.css'
```